# como agregar elementos a una lista que es un valor en un diccionario

Tags: python, bucles, diccionarios

estoy intentando recorrer una lista cuyos elementos son diccionarios:

```
terrenos = [
    {"manager_id": 6, "farm_id": 1, "type_id": 1, "year": 2019, "area": 175600},
    {"manager_id": 1, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 4, "year": 2019, "area": 57560},
    {"manager_id": 5, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 2, "year": 2020, "area": 2756000},
    {"manager_id": 2, "farm_id": 2, "type_id": 3, "year": 2021, "area": 875601},
    {"manager_id": 3, "farm_id": 1, "type_id": 1, "year": 2020, "area": 275677},
    {"manager_id": 5, "farm_id": 2, "type_id": 2, "year": 2017, "area": 1756902},
    {"manager_id": 3, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 2, "year": 2018, "area": 175636},
    {"manager_id": 2, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 3, "year": 2020, "area": 275665},
    {"manager_id": 4, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 4, "year": 2018, "area": 175651},
    {"manager_id": 5, "farm_id": 1, "type_id": 1, "year": 2018, "area": 77560},
    {"manager_id": 1, "farm_id": 2, "type_id": 1, "year": 2019, "area": 775656}
    ]
```

lo que quiero obtener es un diccionario cuyas claves sean los valores de 'farm_id' y los valores sean una lista de los valores de 'manager_id'.

hasta ahora solo he podido hacer la estructura del diccionario pero no he podido agregar los valores de 'manager_id':

```
list_granja_manager = {} 
managers = []
for i in terrenos:
    if list_granja_manager.get(i['farm_id']) != None:
        list_granja_manager[i['farm_id']] = managers
        managers.append(i['manager_id'])
    else:
        list_granja_manager[i['farm_id']] = []

print(list_granja_manager)
```

y me genera esto:

```
{1: [5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2], 3: [5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2], 2: [5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2]}
```

y lo que deberia obtener es esto:

```
{1: [6, 3, 5], 3: [1, 5, 3, 2, 4], 2: [2, 5, 1]}
```

agradezco a quien pueda iluminarme!!!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer? ¿Cómo piensas obtener el valor de los `managers`? Tú código está haciendo lo que le dices y a cada entrada en tu lista le estas diciendo que siempre el valor de la entrada en el diccionario sea toda la lista de `managers`. `list_granja_manager[i['farm_id']] = managers`

Comment: justo por esosolicite ayuda, no lograba ver la solucion

Comment: La respuesta de Candid Moe es correcta.

Comment: @jacobo muy correcta, me gustaria ver su solucion con comprension de listas si no es mucha molestia

Comment: ¿En qué ayudaría una solución con comprensión de listas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no quieres que los valores de manager_id salgan repetidos, deberás usar conjuntos. Es decir, en el diccionario `list_granja_managers` las claves son las granjas, y los valores son **conjuntos** de managers. Un conjunto no guarda elementos duplicados.

Además, si haces uso de `defaultdict`, el código se simplifica porque no necesitas verificar si una clave ya estaba en el diccionario o no antes de añadir algo al conjunto. Un `defaultdict` automáticamente crea un valor nuevo (vacío) para la clave, si ésta no existía, al tratar de acceder a ella.

Con estas ideas el código queda así:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_granja_managers = defaultdict(set)
for t in terrenos:
  list_granja_managers[t["farm_id"]].add(t["manager_id"])
```

### Explicaciones

A `defaultdict()` hay que pasarle el tipo de los valores del diccionario que vamos a crear. En este caso le paso `set` porque quiero que los valores sean conjuntos. Eso hace que cuando intentes acceder a `list_granja_managers[clave]`, si la clave no existía, se creará y se le asociará un conjunto vacío (si ya existía se obtendrá el conjunto que ya tenía). A ese conjunto se le añade un nuevo elemento con `.add()`. No pasa nada por tratar de meter varias veces un mismo elemento, porque el conjunto no guardará repetidos.

### Resultado

La variable `list_granja_managers` final tiene este valor:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {1: {3, 5, 6}, 3: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2: {1, 2, 5}})
```

Aunque es un `defaultdict` y al imprimirlo se ve un poco raro, se comporta a todos los efectos como un diccionario. Puedes acceder a sus claves normalmente.

Si de todas formas no te gusta que se vea así, puedes convertirlo fácilmente a un diccionario "normal": `dict(list_granja_managers)`. Si tampoco te gusta ver los valores como conjuntos y prefieres tenerlos como listas, puedes usar una expresión como la siguiente para convertirlo todo:

```
list_granja_managers = { k: list(v) for k,v in list_granja_managers.items() }
```

Con esto el resultado final será:

```
{1: [3, 5, 6], 2: [1, 2, 5], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias por tu aporte @abulafia

Answer (score 2):

Una solución:

```
salida = {}
for dic in terrenos:
    id = dic["farm_id"]
    if id not in salida:
        salida[id] = []
    salida[id].append(dic["manager_id"])
```

El código recorre la lista de terrenos. De cada uno extrae el `farm_id` y revisa que esté en el diccionario de salida. Si no es así, crea una entrada con una lista vacía.

Luego agrega el `manager_id` a la lista en formación.

#### Demo

```
terrenos = [
    {"manager_id": 6, "farm_id": 1, "type_id": 1, "year": 2019, "area": 175600},
    {"manager_id": 1, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 4, "year": 2019, "area": 57560},
    {"manager_id": 5, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 2, "year": 2020, "area": 2756000},
    {"manager_id": 2, "farm_id": 2, "type_id": 3, "year": 2021, "area": 875601},
    {"manager_id": 3, "farm_id": 1, "type_id": 1, "year": 2020, "area": 275677},
    {"manager_id": 5, "farm_id": 2, "type_id": 2, "year": 2017, "area": 1756902},
    {"manager_id": 3, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 2, "year": 2018, "area": 175636},
    {"manager_id": 2, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 3, "year": 2020, "area": 275665},
    {"manager_id": 4, "farm_id": 3, "type_id": 4, "year": 2018, "area": 175651},
    {"manager_id": 5, "farm_id": 1, "type_id": 1, "year": 2018, "area": 77560},
    {"manager_id": 1, "farm_id": 2, "type_id": 1, "year": 2019, "area": 775656}
    ]

salida = {}
for dic in terrenos:
    id = dic["farm_id"]
    if id not in salida:
        salida[id] = []
    salida[id].append(dic["manager_id"])

print(salida)
```

produce:

```
{1: [6, 3, 5], 3: [1, 5, 3, 2, 4], 2: [2, 5, 1]}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: gracias @Candid Moe, podrias profundizar su respuesta con comprension de listas por favor?

Comment: probe su codigo y funciona bien sin embargo cuando agrega los valores de 'manager_id' en cada lista los guarda repetidos asi                                            
 {1: [6, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 6], 3: [1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1], 2: [2, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 2]}             
 en lugar de                                                                                                         {1: [6, 3, 5], 3: [1, 5, 3, 2, 4], 2: [2, 5, 1]}.............. como se podria corregir esa repeticion de elementos?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que ejecutas el código correcto? El código de @Candid Moe funciona perfectamente.

Comment: si use el mismo codigo pero me guarda los valores duplicados en la lista